# Azure Log Analytics parse WAF data (string data in general)

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-application-gateway, azure-data-explorer

Trying to parse the below string from Azure WAF logs.

```
Matched Data: \x22:\x22SURVEY_0001\x22,\x22e found within REQUEST_COOKIES:cspSurvey: {\x22surveyId\x22:\x22SURVEY_0001\x22,\x22exit\x22:1}
```

I want to return the cookie name, which is after REQUEST_COOKIES: and the cookie value which is after the cookie name (cspSurvey in this example)

I tried this ugly code, but the array index of the cookie name is not always the same.

```
| extend cookie_value  = split(details_data_s, ' ')[-1]
| extend cookie = split(split(details_data_s, ' ')[-2],':')[1]
```

Below is my fully query

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS"
| where OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayFirewall"
| where details_data_s contains "cookie"
| extend cookie_value  = split(details_data_s, ' ')[-1]
| extend cookie = split(split(details_data_s, ' ')[-2],':')[1]
| project clientIp_s, requestUri_s, ruleGroup_s, details_data_s, cookie, cookie_value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using the `parse` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parseoperator

```
print value = 'Matched Data: \x22:\x22SURVEY_0001\x22,\x22e found within REQUEST_COOKIES:cspSurvey: {\x22surveyId\x22:\x22SURVEY_0001\x22,\x22exit\x22:1}'
| parse value with * "REQUEST_COOKIES:" cookie_name ": " cookie_value:dynamic
```