# Azure Log Analytics parse String

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to parse a string from Azure Logs. This is from the `intunedevice` table, and unfortunately the `CreateDate` column is a string and not a date format. So I want to grab this string value and do some transformation in order to compare it with `now()`.
But my problem is that I am unable to fetch the data using regex.

FYI: The format of the `CreatedDate` string value is as follows:

```
2021-05-17 07:33:41.0000000
```

I would like to only get the date (e.g., `2021-05-17`) in the test result below.

I am trying the following:

```
IntuneDevices | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) | parse kind=regex  CreatedDate with "(\\d\\d\\d\\d[-]\\d\\d[-]\\d\\d)*" test  | project TimeGenerated, CreatedDate, now(), test
```

**Result**:

```
TimeGenerated [UTC]
2021-08-30T05:08:42.8809Z
CreatedDate
2021-05-17 07:33:41.0000000
Column1 [UTC]
2021-08-30T12:40:53.296239Z
test
07:33:41.0000000
```

So the parse works, but it takes the values away ...

```
IntuneDevices | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) | parse kind=regex CreatedDate with * '(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})' test | project TimeGenerated, CreatedDate, now(), test
```

**Result**:

```
TimeGenerated [UTC]
2021-08-30T05:08:42.8809Z
CreatedDate
2021-05-17 07:33:41.0000000
Column1 [UTC]
2021-08-30T12:40:53.296239Z
test
07:33:41.0000000
```

So I pushed it a bit differently, but as you can see below the Message is empty when I parse the date...

```
print m = '18/03/2020 07:08:23 1164 PACKET 000000C164RF56B0 UDP Rcv 10.128.151.34 076e Q [2021-05-17 07:33:41.0000000] A (10)indelpus03(6)kworld(4)kay(3)com(0)' | extend Message = extract(@'\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\]', 1, m)
```

**Message**:

```
/empty/
```

But when using just a text sample, like `aaaaa`, it works...

```
print m = '18/03/2020 07:08:23 1164 PACKET 000000C164RF56B0 UDP Rcv 10.128.151.34 076e Q [aaaaa] A (10)indelpus03(6)kworld(4)kay(3)com(0)' | extend Message = extract(@'\[(.*)\]', 1, m)
```

**Message**:

```
aaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [parse operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) which will help you in fetching the data in regex
Below is the example of code on how to use parse values.

```
let Traces = datatable(EventText:string)
[
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=invalid_number, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=15, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00, releaseTime=invalid_datetime, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:00)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=20, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=22, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:41:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01)",
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=invalid_number, sliceNumber=16, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:41:00, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:00)"
];
Traces  
| parse EventText with * "resourceName=" resourceName ", totalSlices=" totalSlices:long * "sliceNumber=" sliceNumber:long * "lockTime=" lockTime ", releaseTime=" releaseTime:date "," * "previousLockTime=" previouLockTime:date ")" *  
| project resourceName ,totalSlices , sliceNumber , lockTime , releaseTime , previousLockTime
```

Also check the [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56229700) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986882/azure-log-analytics-parse-json) with the related discussions.

Comment: Thank you for having taken the time to answer. As you can see in my example I am using parse operator. I am able to get the data easily if I just do a rough basic parse.
My issue stand on the REGEX expression. I am sorry if  I wasn't clear about that. I am unable to get my REGEX to work and to return the data between ()

I am trying to get the 2021-05-17 part of the data only instead of the whole 2021-05-17 07:33:41.0000000 . Today my result only displays... 07:33:41.0000000

Answer (score 0):

So my REGEX was indeed a bit wrong. I corrected it like this and it seems now I have the right result :

```
print m = '18/03/2020 07:08:23 1164 PACKET 000000C164RF56B0 UDP Rcv 10.128.151.34 076e Q [2021-05-17 07:33:41.0000000] A (10)indelpus03(6)kworld(4)kay(3)com(0)' | extend Message = extract(@'\[(\d{4}.*\d{2}.*\d{2})\s.*]', 1, m)
```

and for my very specific issue with the CreatedDate I did this (as a test and functionning) :

```
IntuneDevices | extend  Trace=CreatedDate | extend Crea = extract(@'(\d{4}.*\d{2}.*\d{2})\s.*', 1, Trace) | project Crea, Trace
```